# Problema con una expresión matemática en WEKA

Tags: programación-funcional

estoy intentando añadir un atributo a un archivo de datos utilizando WEKA. El nuevo atributo ("presión arterial gruesa") se basa en otro atributo (en concreto en "presión sanguínea" que es el número 4 dentro de la lista de los atributos) y se define así:

**Presión arterial gruesa** será Baja si la presión de la sangre es menor o igual a 120, Normal si la presión sanguínea es mayor de 120 pero menor o igual que 150 y Alta si la presión sanguínea es mayor de 150.

La expresión matemática que yo he definido para representar esto es esta:

ifelse((A4 < 120 || A4 = 120), A4 = 'Low', ifelse((A4 > 120 && (A4 < 150 || A4 = 150)), A4 = 'Normal',
A4 = 'High'))

Como véis no he incluido ningún <= ,esto se debe a que WEKA me lanza un error que dice que sólo puedo usar el <= cuando los valores son float (y el atributo "presión sanguínea" no es un float).

El error que me lanza con el código que tengo en este momento es: Syntax error at token OR. He probado también a escribir OR en vez de ||, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No creo que sea la solución, porque desconozco la sintaxis del WEKA, pero puedes simplificar el <= sumandole uno, por lo cual en (A4 < 120 || A4 = 120) puedes poner A4<121 y asi no usar el operador lógico OR, lo mismo con el (A4 < 150 || A4 = 150) usando (A4<151)...

Comment: Gracias, eso ha arreglado parte del problema ahora da un nuevo error: Expression must be of double type, alguna idea para solucionar esto?

Comment: Puede ser que A4 este definido de tipo Double, esto es numérico con decimales y le estas asignando valores alfanuméricos o de String